# Limit of sequence of continuous time martingales is a martingale

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, conditional-expectation, stochastic-analysis

Let $X^1, X^2, X^3,\ldots $ be $L^2$-integrable martingales. Assume that for each $t\in[0,T]$ there exists an $X_t\in L^2(\Omega)$, such that $X_t^n\rightarrow X_t$ in $L^2(\Omega)$ for $n\rightarrow\infty$.

I want to show, that $(X_t)_{t\in[0,T]}$ is a martingale. This is the first part of *Exercise 21.4.3* taken from *Achim Klenke, Probability Theory*.

The objective is to find, that $E[X_t|\mathcal{F}_s]=X_s$ for any $s\le t$. The confusing part for me is, that this should hold almost surely, right? My rather foolish attempt would be to use the dominated convergence theorem for conditional expectations, but in this case I would need a $Y_t\in L^1(\Omega)$ with $|X^n_t|\le Y_t$ and that $X_t^n\rightarrow X_t$ almost surely for $n\rightarrow\infty$, such that each equality of
$$E[X_t|\mathcal{F}_s]=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}E[X_t^n|\mathcal{F}_s]=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}X_s^n=X_s$$
holds almost surely and not only in $L^1(\Omega)$. Or am I overcomplicating things here?

Any hint or help is appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dominated convergence theorem cannot be used here since there is no dominating function.

By Jensen's inequality for conditional expectations we get $E(E[(X_t^{n}-X_t)|\mathcal F_s])^{2}\le E(E[(X_t^{n}-X_t)^{2}|\mathcal F_s])=E(X_t^{n}-X_t)^{2} \to 0$. Thus, $E[X_t^{n}|\mathcal F_s) \to  E[X_t|\mathcal F_s)$ in $L^{2}$. This implies almost sure convergence along  a subsequence. Taking limits in $E[X_t^{n}|\mathcal F_s) =X_s^{n}$ we get $E[X_t|\mathcal F_s) =X_s$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Is the limit "independent" of the subsequence? My impression is, that I potentially have to take for each $s$ another subsequence? Is this still consistent?

Comment: Yes, you have to take a subsequence for the left side and then  a further subsequence for the right side so that we get almost sure converegnce on both sides. @user408858

Comment: Thank you! Ok, so we find $E[X_t|\mathcal{F}_s]=X_s$ almost surely for any pair $s\le t$, since there is always a subsequence for any pair $s\le t$, right? (The fact that $L^2$ convergence implies a.s. convergence along subsequence is clear to me. I am somehow only confused by the fact, that the subsequences can be different for any of the pairs $s\le t$. But yes, in the end it says $E[X_t|\mathcal{F}_s]=X_s$ almost surely, which are random variables, that are not dependend of a sequence.)

Comment: To prove martingale property we fix $s$ and $t$. Of course,  the exceptional set will depend on $s$ and $t$ and that is fine in the definition of  a martingale. @user408858